# Laravel Created At The Same Date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the `users` created on the same date, but the time on my database is in UTC, so when a `user` is created 10:00 pm (local time), it is stored as 01:00 am of the next day, so when I use `whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::now('America/Sao_Paulo'))` it doesn't get that `user`.

Comment: No need to use `Carbon::today` because laravel uses function `now()` instead as a helper function


`Model::whereDay('date', now()->day)->get();`

Comment: thanks for the tip, I actually use just `Now()`, and it works, don't know why I put Carbon here. I think I got the code from another question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `whereBetween` instead

```
Model::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])->get();
```

Other possible way :

```
where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'));
```

```
whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

```
whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but still get the data related to UTC, I need the data created on the same day, related ro local time.

Comment: What is your current timezone in your config?

Comment: UTC, i need to keep it in UTC because other countries with different time zones will have access to the reports

Comment: Try instead `Carbon::now('UTC')`

Comment: The problem is when it is (2020-09-05 22:00) in my local time, it save as (2020-09-06 00:00) in the database, so when i try to retrieve the data from day 5, it do not get this entry, because it is on day 6.

Comment: Try `whereBetween` instead `Model::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])->get();`

Comment: It still not work, but I gave me an Idea of how to make it work `User::whereBetween('created_at',[Carbon\Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Sao_Paulo')->startOfDay()->utc(), Carbon\Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Sao_Paulo')->endOfDay()->utc()])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @sta who suggested to use `whereBetween()` instead, I first got the start/end of the day in my local time, then converted it back to UTC.

```
$start_of_day = Carbon::now('America/Sao_Paulo')->startOfDay()->utc();
$end_of_day = Carbon::now('America/Sao_Paulo')->endOfDay()->utc();
return User::whereBetween('created_at',[$start_of_day,$end_of_day])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the users created at the same date why not simply group by created_at, then you don't have to care about those details.

Comment: Like i said, the created_at is stored in UTC and i need the users created on the same day related to local time.